# Vim remove lag for ESC and Ctrl-[

Tags: vim

When I'm using a multiline insert, if I do `Ctrl-V`, `DownArrow` multiple times to select, `I` to insert, then say I type a space:

```
 foo
bar
qux
```

Now if I `Ctrl-C`, it becomes

```
foo
bar
qux
```

**instantly**.

But if I do `Ctrl-[` or `ESC`, Vim **lags for half a sec**, then insert a space before all three lines

```
 foo
 bar
 qux
```

Similarly, say I'm working on some Ruby code

```
def foo
  bar
  end
```

I'm still on insert mode and the cursor stays after `end`.
If I `Ctrl-C`, the `end` stays there, incorrectly indented.
If I `Ctrl-[` or `ESC`, Vim **lags for half a sec**, then indent the `end` properly, so it becomes:

```
def foo
  bar
end
```

How do I remove this lag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal sends *escape sequences* to Vim (or any other program) when you press certain keys or perform certain actions. For example, try typing `cat` and pressing the up arrow, and you get this:

```
llama@llama:~$ cat
^[[A
```

Note that when you press the up arrow key, what your terminal is really getting is <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (in quick succession). (The `^[` stands for Esc.)

Similar escape sequences are sent for when you turn the scroll wheel on your mouse, etc.

Vim interprets these escape sequences (that's how, for example, you can use the scroll wheel from within a terminal to scroll in Vim). But since they start with an Escape character, so this creates some ambiguity.

For example, when Vim gets an Escape character in insert mode, it has to decide whether it means "exit insert mode" or if it's the first part of an escape sequence ("scroll up").

Vim has several settings for this: `ttimeoutlen`, which is the amount of "lag" before Vim decides "okay, this isn't an escape sequence, it's an actual escape character." This is in milliseconds, and you can change it if you would like with `set ttimeoutlen=foo` in your .vimrc (where foo is the amount of time Vim will wait in milliseconds).

There's also the `esckeys` option, which tells Vim whether to interpret these escape sequences at all. If you don't care about them, you can remove the timeout entirely (but also the function of the escape sequences) with `set noesckeys` in your .vimrc.

Comment: Thanks :-) I went with `noesckeys`, and it's interesting to observe how the four Arrow keys are producing `ABCD` in insert mode now.

Comment: @octref Heh... think of it as forcing you to stop using the inefficient arrow keys and use more productive navigation keys instead. :)